# Connecting WinSCP with Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, putty, winscp

I'm trying to connect Winscp with virtual machine. I'm working on Windows,and this problem is killing me for 5 hours. Studied a lot of examples, but I can't find out what is the problem. I tried to connect with putty to, but connection is every time refused. Tried to connect with every protocol, but didn't help. I even can't install ssh into Ubuntu, because something is blocking but not firewall(failed to fetch us archive ubuntu com). Port forwarding too wasn't very helpful.

1st Adapter is NAT, and second host-only.

Problem is that I need to enter home directory, and add some files, so I'm trying to find the easiest way to do this.

I would really appreciate any help. Here is my ifconfig, ip a, and interfaces picture.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R16tt.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Check in the guest and see by running ifconfig as root that the network adapter has been successfully configured and the interfaces have IP. Try connecting to those IPs instead of hostname. And show some research - what have you tried?

Comment: Which adapter is used by VM? The NAT or the host only? If using the NAT, you have to create port forwarding for NAT:port to VM:port.

Comment: Have you installed openssh-server on the ubuntu guest?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following step to configure.

1- Run ipconfig /all on your windows machine and see which ip are assigned to your virtual adopters.

2- Assign the same range ip to your virtual machine. For example:
If on virtual adopter ip is: 192.168.130.1
Then assign ip to your vm as: 192.168.130.*
and set gateway to : 192.168.130.1
and restart the service network and check the reachability by pinging from both side.

3- If You able to ping then you will be able to use internate on your VM. Then install the ssh.

Now you will be able to use.